Check if member function is defined using SFINAE instead of requires clause
I want to check if a specific member function of a class is defined and simultaneously not disabled by SFINAE. The following code works:
struct A {
    int foo() { return 3; }
};

struct B {};

template <class, class = void>
struct hasFoo : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct hasFoo<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())>>
    : std::true_type {};

template <class T>
    struct hasFoo20 : std::bool_constant < requires(T t) {
    t.foo();
} > {};

static_assert(hasFoo<A>::value);
static_assert(!hasFoo<B>::value);
static_assert(hasFoo20<A>::value);
static_assert(!hasFoo20<B>::value);

Link
but if I have a member function in A, which itself is enabled or disabled using SFINAE, I cannot get it the following working:
template <typename T = int>
struct A {
    template <typename = void, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>, bool> = true>
    T foo() {
        return 3;
    }
};

template <class, class = void>
struct hasFoo : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct hasFoo<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())>>
    : std::true_type {};

template <class T>
    struct hasFoo20 : std::bool_constant < requires(T t) {
    t.foo();
} > {};

static_assert(hasFoo<A<>>::value);
static_assert(!hasFoo<A<double>>::value);

static_assert(hasFoo20<A<>>::value);
static_assert(!hasFoo20<A<double>>::value);

Link
For the second case, only the C++20 code works as I want it, but I have to make it C++17 compatible.
The SFINAE code fails with error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, bool>', which is expected since the enable_if_t of foo is evaluated.
Can someone give me a hint? Thanks!

The first step of substitution failure is not an error (SFINAE) is substitution. If a template doesn't substitute anything and causes an error, it's just a hard error. Therefore, SFINAE must be dependent on the template parameters it appears in. Even though T looks like a template parameter of foo, it's not, it's from the enclosing class.
One solution is
template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, int>, bool> = false>
T foo() {
    return 3;
}


Ah thanks, I overlook that one. Thanks! Basically I was thinking about member functions that will no compile and therefore are disabled. Now the SFINAE case is considered but I'm still curious about a similar case: Consider foo is defined in library code and for some templates it is ill-defined due to some triggering of a static_assert. Now I also don't see an option how to detect this. Do you have an idea? Basically I'm talking about a scenario like: https://godbolt.org/z/oa4v4jY5d or should this be posed as a new question?

@rath3t If it's another question, you should post a new question. Be sure to research if the question is already asked.
